# iOS set default back button appearance

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, default, back

I want to set a default behaviour for the navigation bar's back button, so it will look the same throughout the app. I also want to remove the default text, which I have already figured out.

I have tried the following without success:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_backarrow"]];

//set default back text to @""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **UIBarButtonItem**

```
UIImage *backButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_backarrow"]
                                resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 5, 4, 5)];

    // Back button nav bar items
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonImage
                                                      forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonImage
                                                  forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonImage
                                                  forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-2.0f, 1.0f)
                                                     forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: I got the image to show this way but it still shows the old back icon as well as the back text, how do I remove them?

Comment: @Felix Dumit I hava updated the answer, it should fix your problem

Comment: Displays duplicate buttons